# Rails Api Rspec Test that takes params on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

**routes.rb**

```
get 'students/name_starts_with/:letter', to: 'students#name_starts_with'
get 'students/with_last_name/:last', to: 'students#with_last_name'
```

**students_controller.rb**

```
def name_starts_with
  @students = Student.all.select{|s| s.first_name.start_with?(params[:letter]}
  render json: @students.to_json
end

def with_last_name
  @students = Student.all.select{|s| s.last_name == params[:last]}
  render json: @students.to_json
end
```

**students_controller_spec.rb**

```
context '#name_starts_with' do
  let!(:first_student){Student.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}
  it "starts with #{first_student.first_name.split('').first}" do
    get :name_starts_with
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    expect(first_student.first_name.split('').first).to be('J')
  end
end

context '#with_last_name' do
  let!(:first_student){Student.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe'}
  it "has last name #{first_student.last_name}" do
    get :with_last_name
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    expect(first_student.last_name).to be('Doe')
  end
end
```

I have seeded bunch of student names. As far as I know both of these should be get routes/get requests. I am getting same error for both:-

```
Failure/Error: get :name_starts_with
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"name_starts_with", :controller=>"students"}
     # ./spec/controllers/students_controller_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Should they be POST routes instead. Am I missing something. Am I doing whole thing wrong. Can somebody please help me solve this issue please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is route matching error. parameter letter is missing in this call.

Replace

```
get :name_starts_with
```

with

```
get :name_starts_with, letter: first_student.first_name.split('').first
```

I think this will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds stupid, but is your StudentsController inheriting from ApplicationController? (ApplicationController inherits from ActionController::Base

...and I'm not sure if you need the @students.to_json if you already declared render :json in your controller. just put render json: @students